# MYSQL: Write a trigger to record the message "A new row is inserted" and the time of insertion in a separate table when inserting a new row into table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  EmployeeID INT,
  LastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Birthdate date 
);
```

I need to write a trigger to record the message "A new row is inserted", and the time of insertion into a new separate table called Employees_audit when inserting a new row into the Employees table.

I am stumped with this and have looked at example triggers to help me but I cannot quite figure out what to do. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What are you stumped with ? the message recording or the insert to Employees_audit or both? Please publish what you have so far.

Comment: Please refer to [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) and show what you have researched so far, why it has not helped and explain exactly what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20trigger%2C%20we,To%20insert%20record%20in%20Table1.&text=To%20check%20if%20the%20records%20are%20inserted%20in%20both%20tables%20or%20not.) and [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/)

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  EmployeeID INT,
  LastName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Birthdate date 
);

create table Employees_audit (
  note varchar(255),
  inserted_record_dt datetime,
  EmployeeID int
);
```

The trigger you need:

```
create trigger Insert_Employees_audit after insert on Employees
 for each row
 begin
 insert into Employees_audit (EmployeeID,note, inserted_record_dt) values (new.EmployeeID,'A new row is inserted',  now());
end
```

Some data example

```
insert into Employees values (1,'Test','Test','2000-01-01');
```

Result of:

```
select * 
from Employees_audit;

           note         inserted_record_dt     EmployeeID
A new row is inserted   2022-11-21 10:01:34        1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/KGa4ditu

Comment: inserted_record_dt should be autoutilized column.

Comment: @Akina yes, that's another way of doing.  Though `should be` would be better `could be`

Comment: For audit? I'd say that it "must be" - audit must be non-effected by any external factor, and any value which may be assigned automatically must be assigned by this way.